# How can I reshape my dataframe using reshape package?

Tags: r, reshape

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
step  var1  score1  score2
1      a    0        0
2      b    1        1
3      d    1        1
4      e    0        0
5      g    0        0
1      b    1        1
2      a    1        0
3      d    1        0
4      e    0        1
5      f    1        1
1      g    0        1
2      d    1        1
etc.
```

Because I need to correlate variabeles a-g (their scores are in score1) with score2 in only step 5 I think i need to schange my dataset into this first:

```
a   b   c   d   e   f   g   score2_step5
0   1       1   0       0   0
1   1       1   0   1       1
            1           0 
etc.
```

I am pretty sure that the Reshape package should be able to help me to do the job, but I haven't been able to make it work yet. 
Can anyone help me? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another version. In case there is no `step = 5`, the value for `score2_step = 0`. Assuming your `data.frame` is `df`:

```
require(reshape2)
out <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq(1, nrow(df), by=5), function(ix) {
    iy <- min(ix+4, nrow(df))
    df.b <- df[ix:iy, ]
    tt <- dcast(df.b, 1 ~ var1, fill = 0, value.var = "score1", drop=F)
    tt$score2_step5 <- 0
    if (any(df.b$step == 5)) {
        tt$score2_step5 <- df.b$score2[df.b$step == 5]
    }
    tt[,-1]
}))

> out
   a b d e f g score2_step5
2  0 1 1 0 0 0            0
21 1 1 1 0 1 0            1
22 0 0 1 0 0 0            0
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want 7 correlations between the variables a-g and score2_step5--is that correct? First, you're going to need another variable. I'm assuming that `step` repeats continuously from 1 to 5; if not, this is going to be more complicated. I'm assuming your data is called `df`. I also prefer the newer `reshape2` package, so I'm using that.

```
df$block <- rep(1:(nrow(df)/5),each=5)
df.molten <- melt(df,id.vars=c("var1", "step", "block"),measure.vars=c("score1"))
df2 <- dcast(df.molten, block ~ var1)
score2_step5 <- df$score2[df$step==5]
```

and then finally

```
cor(df2, score2_step5, use='pairwise')
```

There's an extra column (`block`) in `df2` that you can get rid of or just ignore.

Answer (score 0):

I added another row to your example data because my code doesn't work unless there is a step-5 observation in every block.

```
dat <- read.table(textConnection("
step  var1  score1  score2
1      a    0        0
2      b    1        1
3      d    1        1
4      e    0        0
5      g    0        0
1      b    1        1
2      a    1        0
3      d    1        0
4      e    0        1
5      f    1        1
1      g    0        1
2      d    1        1
5      a    1        0"),header=TRUE)
```

Like @JonathanChristensen, I made another variable (I called it `rep` instead of `block`), and I made `var1` into a factor (since there are no `c` values in the example data set given and I wanted a placeholder).

```
dat <- transform(dat,var1=factor(var1,levels=letters[1:7]),
                 rep=cumsum(step==1))
```

`tapply` makes the table of `score1` values:

```
tab <- with(dat,tapply(score1,list(rep,var1),identity))
```

add the `score2`, step-5 values:

```
data.frame(tab,subset(dat,step==5,select=score2))
```